# How to introspect Java Web Start GUI Application?

Tags: java, user-interface, web, introspection

There is an Java Web Start GUI Application. As I understand it is based on Swing. So the question is how to make an introspection in that application? Is there any way to accomplish that? For example, in case of HTML there is a Firebug application that can help to introspect the source of any HTML element. And I want to get a way that can help me to know the source of any button or item event handler.
For example, if I push button "btn1" then textbox "txtBox" will show message "Msg". And I want to get the sequence of steps that make message to shown.

Comment: Ok, I see that it is possible to get all client's jar files in java cache. Next step is to figure out how to easily to get GUI elements handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this answers your question since you don't say what are you trying to do, but if you want to do GUI testing don't reinvent the wheel. There are [GUI Testing Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools) free and commmercial that do what you describe.

Comment: I don't have any source files, only classes. Does this tool work with the binary delivered application?

Comment: There are many tools.And yes some of the tools don't use the source code.Check the list and see what fits your needs.If you (or your company) can afford it check out the commercial as well